# TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, lambda

## Sample dataframe :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"Hashtags" : ["[u'AAPHealthCare4All']", "[]", "[u'NDTV']", "[u'CBI', u'PrannoyRoy', u'Delhi', u'Emergency']" , "[u'CBI']" ]})
```

## Sample Output

```
({"Hashtags" : ["#AAPHealthCare4All", " ", "NDTV", "CBI", "PrannoyRoy", "Delhi", "Emergency", "CBI"]})
```

## This is my code :

```
# Splitting Hashtags
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("2.csv")
df1 = df.drop('Hashtags', axis=1).join(
             df.Hashtags
             .str
             .split(expand=True)
             .stack()
             .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
             .rename('Hashtags')           
             )
df1.to_csv('string_HT.csv', index=False)
# Cleaning HASHTAGS
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] =df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("u'  ',")

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] = df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("',")

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] = df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("u'")


df1['Hashtags'] = "#" + df1['Hashtags']
df1.rename(columns={'Favorite_Count' : 'Favorite Count','Retweet_Count' :'Retweet Count', 'User_Mentions':'User Mentions','User_Location'   : 'User Location','No_of_Followers': 'No of Followers','Status_Count':'Status Count','Geo_Enabled':'Geo Enabled','Compound_Score':'Compound Score'}, inplace=True) #Rename column names to suit tableau file
df1.to_csv('string_HT.csv', index=False)
```

## This is what i'm trying to achieve

I'm trying to add '#' before each hashtags string in the column, after cleaning it and removing unnecessary brackets, characters and quotes/commas. 
I've performed a lot of operations in the whole code for data cleaning and manipulation, it's pointing towards this error.

## Error

```
  File "C:/../filename.py", line 469, in <module>
    df1['Hashtags'] = "#" + df1['Hashtags']

  File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 715, in wrapper
    result = wrap_results(safe_na_op(lvalues, rvalues))

  File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 676, in safe_na_op
    return na_op(lvalues, rvalues)

  File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 662, in na_op
    result[mask] = op(x[mask], y)

  File "C:\ANACONDA\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    radd=arith_method(lambda x, y: y + x, names('radd'), op('+'),

TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best is not use `iterrows` looping, if exist faster vectorized solutions.

Maybe help replace:

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] =df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("u'  ',")

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] = df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("',")

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Hashtags'] = df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("u'")
```

to double [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) - first remove chars `u,` and second `'`:

```
df1['Hashtags'] = df1['Hashtags'].str.strip("[u, ]").str.strip("'")
df1['Hashtags'] = "#" + df1['Hashtags']
```

Or add `astype`:

```
df1['Hashtags'] = "#" + df1['Hashtags'].astype(str)
```